# RoboAsyncTask custom loading animation

Tags: android, roboguice

I have extended RoboAsyncTask implemented all needed methods, but while data loading it's displaying default loading animation.

I have made my custom loading dialog but default loading animation on fragment still displaying. It is possible to remove it? Or change animation image?

```
public class ContactFragment extends RoboSherlockListFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ContactLoadingTask contactLoadingTask = new ContactLoadingTask(this.getActivity());
    contactLoadingTask.execute();
}


private class ContactLoadingTask extends RoboAsyncTask<List<Contact>> {

    @Inject
    ContactParser contactParser;

    protected ContactLoadingTask(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Contact> call() throws Exception {
        return contactParser.getContacts();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSuccess(List<Contact> contacts) throws Exception {
        setListAdapter(new ContactArrayAdapter(ContactFragment.this.getActivity(), contacts));
    }

}

}
```

Launching this code i see loading animation on my fragment before contacts are loaded

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

`RoboAsyncTask` does **not** deal with any animation, or anything visible by the user. It only execute code in a background thread.

I think the animation you're talking about is played automatically by `ListFragment` when you call `setListAdapter()`, as stated in the `setListShown()` method [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListShown%28boolean%29)

Sadly it doesn't seem you can override this animation, so you might have to use a standard Fragment and manage the ListView yourself. You can look at the [source code of ListFragment](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/ListFragment.java#ListFragment.setListShown%28boolean,boolean%29) to see how this is done

---

If you just want to **disable the animation**, you might try to use  `setListShownNoAnimation` just before setting your list adapter:

```
@Override
protected void onSuccess(List<Contact> contacts) throws Exception {
    setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    setListAdapter(new ContactArrayAdapter(ContactFragment.this.getActivity(), contacts));
}
```